# How to print tickets using .NET 6 WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-6.0

I'm trying to create a program for printing tickets using .NET 6 WPF. After running the program, the document appears in the print queue, but it only prints a blank page. I've also tried using a regular printer, and the situation is the same.

Below is my test.

First test.

```
FixedPage fixedPage = new FixedPage();
fixedPage.Width = 320;
fixedPage.Height = 267;

Style textStyle = new Style(typeof(TextBlock));
Setter sWeight = new Setter(TextBlock.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold);
textStyle.Setters.Add(sWeight);
Setter sFontColor = new Setter(TextBlock.ForegroundProperty, System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black);
textStyle.Setters.Add(sFontColor);
TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
textBlock.Text = content;
textBlock.FontSize = fontSize;
textBlock.Style = textStyle;
textBlock.FontFamily = new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily(fontFamily);
textBlock.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, (double)x);
textBlock.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, (double)y);
fixedPage.Children.Add(textBlock);

PageContent pageContent = new PageContent();
((IAddChild)pageContent).AddChild(fixedPage);
FixedDocument fixedDocument = new FixedDocument();
fixedDocument.Pages.Add(pageContent);
PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
printDialog.PrintDocument(fixedDocument.DocumentPaginator, "Ticket");
```

Second test.

```
FixedPage fixedPage = new FixedPage();
fixedPage.Width = 320;
fixedPage.Height = 267;

Style textStyle = new Style(typeof(TextBlock));
Setter sWeight = new Setter(TextBlock.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold);
textStyle.Setters.Add(sWeight);
Setter sFontColor = new Setter(TextBlock.ForegroundProperty, System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black);
textStyle.Setters.Add(sFontColor);
TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
textBlock.Text = content;
textBlock.FontSize = fontSize;
textBlock.Style = textStyle;
textBlock.FontFamily = new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily(fontFamily);
textBlock.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, (double)x);
textBlock.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, (double)y);
fixedPage.Children.Add(textBlock);

PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
printDialog.PrintVisual(fixedPage, "Ticket");
```

On the printer, I can see an item named 'Ticket' in the print queue, but there is no content.

I don't need any printer selection dialog; I want to print the ticket directly. How can I modify it to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print documents without the `PrintDialog` by using the `LocalProntServer` together with the `XpsDocumentWriter`.

Some notes on your code:

- You should consider using XAML to populate the document. Creating styles and templates is very awkward using C#. You could define a `DataTemplate` and a `ContentControl` in XAML. Add styles to the `ContentControl.Resources` dictionary. All of this can go into a dedicated .xaml file. The `DataTemplate` defines the document layout e.g. `TextBlock` elements etc. You can use the `XamlReader` to convert the XAML text to objects, for example the `ContentControl` markup to a C# object you can use. Then assign the data model that represents the document content to the `ContentControl.Content` property and print it directly or by adding it to a `FixedDocument`. You definitely shouldn't create any visual tree in C#, especially not styles and templates.
- `IAddChild` is an obsolete interface. Don't use it. It could get dropped from the framework any time.
  It's also not necessary to use it as you can simply use the
  `PageContent.Child` property:

  ```
  //((IAddChild)pageContent).AddChild(fixedPage);
  pageContent.Child = fixedPage;
  ```
- The positioning using the attached `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Left` properties is only relevant when the attaching element is the child of a `Canvas`. Otherwise, it doesn't have any effect on the layout.
  You also should consider to use the attached property accessors:

  ```
  //textBlock.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, (double)x);
  Canvas.SetLeft(textBlock, (double)x);
  ```

Example on how to print without the `PrintDialog`:

```cs
private void PrintDocument(FixedDocument document)
{
  var printServer = new LocalPrintServer();

  /* 
   * Select a destination printer using one of the following methods 
   */

  PrintQueue destinationPrinter;

  // Method 1: filter the list of available printers.
  // For example:
  PrintQueueCollection availablePrinters = printServer.GetPrintQueues();
  destinationPrinter = availablePrinters.First(printQueue => printQueue.Name.Contains("PDF", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

  // Method 2: use the default printer
  destinationPrinter = printServer.DefaultPrintQueue;

  // Method 3: pick a particular printer by name e.g., the native PDF printer
  string printerName = "Microsoft Print to PDF";
  destinationPrinter = printServer.GetPrintQueue(printerName);

  /* 
   * Start the printing 
   */

  // Create a XpsDocumentWriter that writes to the printer queue
  XpsDocumentWriter documentWriter = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(destinationPrinter);

  // Handle the 'XpsDocumentWriter.WritingCompleted` event 
  // to continue code after writing has been completed.
  // This is an event based asynchronous API.
  documentWriter.WriteAsync(document);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It resolved my issue. After adding `FixedPage.SetLeft(textBlock, 15);`, the content now appears when printing. Since I require multiple ticket formats and the flexibility to make changes easily, I will continue to create the content in C#.